# Compilación C++ en Visual Studio

Tags: c++, compilador

En sí mi problema es con *Visual Studio*. Al momento de compilar un programa de *C++*, se me cierra, lo llego a ver como si se tratara de un parpadeo, un ejemplo, escribo el clásico hola mundo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hola mundo";
}
```

Como lo dije anteriormente, el mensaje aparece por 1 segundo, en cambio en *CodeBlocks* el mensaje se queda estático. El problema es que yo no quiero usar `system("Pause");` quiero que aparezca como *CodeBlocks*, sin necesidad de poner `system("Pause");` y que no se cierre en 1 segundo.

Comment: Si se necesita colocar para que se quede estatica la consola!!

Comment: Depende del tipo de solución, necesitas crear una aplicación de consola.

Answer (score 1):

Puede tratar <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd>

---

Si lo anterior no le funiona añadir lo siguiente e intentar de nuevo.
Boton derecho en su proyeto para acceder a:

`Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `Linker` -> `System`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

fijese en el campo *SubSystem* poner ...(/SUBSYTEM:...

Answer (score 0):

Agrega "pause" en el campo de argumentos de comando bajo la sección de debugging de las propiedades del proyecto.

ver: http://xoax.net/blog/keeping-the-c-console-window-open/